# Distribution independent libpython path

Tags: python, linux, path

Under newer Ubuntu/Debian versions, `libpython2.7.so` is under `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so` or `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so`, etc. Earlier, they could be found in `/usr/lib/libpython2.7.so`, no matter the architecture. I haven't checked for other distributions. How do I find the path of `libpython2.7.so` with python?

Comment: Are you looking for `locate libpython` or something else?

Comment: what does your `ldd /usr/local/bin/python` show you ?

Comment: `locate libpython` finds quite a lot more than just this single file, and I want to programmatically find the path and supply it to cmake. `ldd /usr/local/bin/python` gives `No such file or directory`, and `ldd /usr/bin/python` gives several library files, but `libpython2.7.so` is not one of them.

Comment: there is a package for this: https://pypi.org/project/find-libpython/

Answer (score 12):

Using `pkg-config` is not the best option - it will not distinguish between different installations of Python, returning only the system installation.  You are better off using the Python executable to discover the location of `libpythonX.Y.so`.

From inside Python:

```
   from distutils import sysconfig;
   print sysconfig.get_config_var("LIBDIR")
```

Or inside a Makefile:

```
   PYTHON_LIBDIR:=$(shell python -c 'from distutils import sysconfig; print sysconfig.get_config_var("LIBDIR")')
```

This will discover the location from whatever Python executable is first in `$PATH` and thus will work if there are multiple Python installations on the system.

Credit to [Niall Fitzgerald](https://github.com/potentialventures/cocotb/issues/128) for pointing this out.

Comment: It gives to me `/usr/lib`, while it's located in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

Comment: didn't work for me. the same problem as Marco Sulla pointed out.

Comment: Same issue. :( Really wish there was a way to do this.

Comment: Note that `LIBDIR` is not set in Windows (the question is about Linux, but someone might still try it). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47423246/get-pythons-lib-path for a portable way.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution which seems to work against system wide Debian and CentOS installation, anaconda on Debian, miniconda on OSX, virtualenv on Debian... but fails for system-wide python on OSX:

```
from distutils import sysconfig;
import os.path as op;
v = sysconfig.get_config_vars();
fpaths = [op.join(v[pv], v['LDLIBRARY']) for pv in ('LIBDIR', 'LIBPL')]; 
print(list(filter(op.exists, fpaths))[0])
```

and here it ran on my laptop:

```
$> for p in python python3 ~/anaconda-4.4.0-3.6/bin/python ~datalad/datalad-master/venvs/dev/bin/python ; do $p -c "from distutils import sysconfig; import os.path as op; v = sysconfig.get_config_vars(); fpaths = [op.join(v[pv], v['LDLIBRARY']) for pv in ('LIBDIR', 'LIBPL')]; print(list(filter(op.exists, fpaths))[0])"; done                                                                                                                               
/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so                                                      
/usr/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so
/home/yoh/anaconda-4.4.0-3.6/lib/libpython3.6m.so
/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so
```

P.S. I had no clue that it is such a problem... bad bad bad Python

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're looking to link against this file. Python is usually installed with `pkgconfig` info to help compile against it. Specifically for the `.so` file, you should use `pkg-config --libs python-2.7`. From Python:

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output(["pkg-config", "--libs", "python-2.7"])
```

If the only flag shown is `-lpython2.7`, you might want to consider reading `/etc/ld.so.conf` to see default locations in which the linker looks for its libraries.